# using classes as functions

Tags: php, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices for static constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368199/best-practices-for-static-constructors)

I want to create an object similar to the way jQuery is set up, that means have a main function and utility functions. I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
class main {
    function __construct() {
        echo 'this is the main usage of the object';
    }
    static function helper() {
        echo 'this is a helper function';
    }
}
```

So using the helper is pretty straightforward: `main::helper();` but in order to use the main function itself I need to use the `new` keyword everytime: `new main()`. Is there any way to make it so that I can call the main function without using the `new` keyword?

Comment: You need to concretise your usage intentions. It's not easy to make the connection between jQuery-like and your intended static function calls (which you already know how to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call with helper for example nameofhelper:

> main::helper('nameofhelper');

Function class:

```
abstract class main {
    function __construct() {
        echo 'this is the main usage of the object';
    }

    public static function helper($name_of_helper)
    {
        $helper = new 'Helper_'.$name_of_helper;
    }
}
```

Helper class:

```
class Helper_nameofhelper
{
    function invoke()
    {
        return 'invokedhelper';
    }
}
```